# Changed name of Docker container, everything broke

Tags: wordpress, nginx, docker, mysqli, docker-compose

I'm new to Docker/Kitematic, and I made a bonehead mistake, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it.

I've got Wordpress running in Docker with nginx/mysqli/etc and all was running flawlessly. When I was in kitematic, I noticed a 'name' field, and it was something like 'travelsite_ngninx_1.' Being the dope I am, I was like 'hmmmm, maybe I can make that more semantic.' So I renamed it, and as soon as I did, everything broke. 'Error connecting to the database' and all that. The sad part is, I can't remember exactly what the name was, or if even reverting that will fix anything.

Is there a way to 'reset' the composer/docker so all of the containers are linked up again? I'm a newb when it comes to YML files, so I'm not even sure what to look for. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Here's my new error after enabling debugging mode on the renamed container:

> 'Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1538'

then theres:

> 'Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1538'

Please help this poor noob idiot out! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I've figured it out. Apparently there's an issue with Kitematic that makes containers not fully destroy. Went into CLI, destroyed all containers, and ran `docker-compose up` and everything is A-1 now! Posted the answer just in case somebody else runs into that issue!